# Lex - not detecting token after adding a new line

Tags: c, lex, pddl

I'm trying to write a program that reads action and its components from a [PDDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planning_Domain_Definition_Language) file. The program should first look for token `:action(` and then `action name` etc.

Following is my lex code:

Note: The answer to this question is mostly related to `:(action` token, `action name` token and `newline` token, so you might only look at those. By SC_ACNAME I mean scan action name etc.

```
%{
#include "myscanner.h"
%}

%START SC_ACNAME SC_PARAMETERS SC_PREDICATE SC_BODY

NAME                                [0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+
TEXT                                [0-9a-zA-Z?_\-( \t]+
TEXT_PARAM                          [0-9a-zA-Z?_\-( \t\n]+
TEXTBREAK                           [ \t\n]+

    int lb_flag=0;
    int pred_lb_flag = 0;

%%

\(:action                                                               {lb_flag++; BEGIN SC_ACNAME; return ACTION;}
<SC_ACNAME>{TEXT}                                                       {BEGIN SC_BODY; return ACTION_NAME;}
<SC_BODY>:parameters                                                    {BEGIN SC_PARAMETERS; return PARAMETER;}
<SC_PARAMETERS>{TEXT_PARAM}                                             {lb_flag++; BEGIN SC_BODY; return PARAMETERS;}  
<SC_BODY>:precondition                                                  {BEGIN SC_PREDICATE; return PRECONDITION;}
<SC_BODY>:effect                                                        {BEGIN SC_PREDICATE; return EFFECT;}
<SC_PREDICATE>\(and                                                     {pred_lb_flag++; return CONJUNCTION;}
<SC_PREDICATE>\(not                                                     {pred_lb_flag++; return NEGATION;}
<SC_PREDICATE>\({NAME}({TEXTBREAK}\?{NAME})+\)                          return PREDICATE;
<SC_PREDICATE>\)                                                        {if(pred_lb_flag) pred_lb_flag--; if(!pred_lb_flag) BEGIN SC_BODY; return RIGHT_BRACKET;}
<SC_BODY>\)                                                             {if(lb_flag) lb_flag--; if(!lb_flag) BEGIN 0; return RIGHT_BRACKET;}
<SC_PREDICATE,SC_BODY,SC_ACNAME>{TEXTBREAK}                             ;   

%%

int yywrap(void)
{
    return 1;
}
```

Header File (myscanner.h):

```
#define ACTION 1
#define ACTION_NAME 2
#define PARAMETER 3
#define PARAMETERS 4
#define PRECONDITION 5
#define EFFECT 6
#define CONJUNCTION 7
#define NEGATION 8
#define PREDICATE 9
#define RIGHT_BRACKET 10
```

Following in my C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myscanner.h"

extern int yylex();
extern int yylineno;
extern char* yytext;

int main(void)
{
    int ntoken, vtoken;

    ntoken = yylex();
    while(ntoken)
    {
        printf("%d", ntoken);
        print("%s", yytext);
        ntoken = yylex();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to tokenise file which contains `(:action move` it detects `:(action` and `action name` as desired and returns ACTION and ACTION_NAME. But when I enter a newline after move (action name), it doesn't detect anything. Why is it not recognising the token `(:action`?

EDIT:

Pass Test Case: domain.pddl

```
(:action move
```

Failure Test Case: domain.pddl

```
(:action move<nl>
```

indicates newline

Comment: I do not understand _when I enter a newline after move (action name)_, I need to enter a newline after _(:action move_ to finish the input, and all seems ok. Please edit your question to give the input(s)

Comment: @bruno Hmm...I did this via a file. Can you try entering new line in a file and then test it? ./a.out < file.pddl

Comment: again, to avoid misunderstanding, give an example of input file, not a description of that file, if you want use <nl> to indicate where the nl are

Comment: @bruno Sure. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encourage you to add for instance `putchar('\n');` before the `return 0;` in *main* to flush what is produced by *printf*, may be you have nothing printed because of that miss ?

If 'f' contains the line `(:action move<nl>` and I execute `a.out < f`  that prints `1(:action2 move` and it is the same when the line is not terminated in 'f' (no  at the end)

Comment: Can you please explain _printf_s part?

Comment: Can you please explain that flush part in a bit more detail. Thanks. My program worked but still i didn't get the concept.

Comment: that depend on the used OS, but when you print on stdout (rather than stderr) the output is buffered, so a flush is needed to see the output, one way to force the flush is to print a newline.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using MacOS.

Comment: Hmm...it's kinda funny that some files in my laptop are running fine while this one is giving error.

Comment: Just test with and without the `putchar('\n');` before the  `return 0;` . At the minimum when you start the execution is a shell the newline allows to see the shell prompt on the a new line

Comment: I didn't said in my answer, but the definition of TEXT and TEXT_PARAM containing space tab and newline seems strange for me while you also have them in TEXTBREAK